# C# ExpressiveAnnotations how to add Asterisk notation when field is requied

Tags: c#, expressiveannotations

Very good library:
https://github.com/jwaliszko/ExpressiveAnnotations

but I don't know how to add asterisk notation when field is required. IS this possible. If yes how?

Code

```
[RequiredIf("IsCustomerInputRequired == true")]
[Display(Name = Translations.Global.USER)]
public string CustomerInput { get; set; }
```

I try with:

```
var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
var isRequired = metaData.ContainerType.GetProperty(metaData.PropertyName).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RequiredIfAttribute), false).Any();
```

but is always `true` what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataAnnotations on your properties to get a slightly different required effect:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

[Required(ErrorMessage="[Education] Please enter the University of Institution.")]
public string School
{
    get { return _school; }
    set { _school = value; OnPropertyChanged();}
}
```

Or you can try your own HtmlHelper extension:

```
public static string RequiredMarkFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper html,     Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
{
    if(ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression,  html.ViewData).IsRequired)
         return "*";
    else
         return string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Thx for hint but RequiredMarkFor method is always false in my example. ANd I am using ExpressiveAnnotations library not simple required field